# Are they the same function? $y = x^2/x$ and $y = x$

Tags: calculus, functions

Are they the same function?

$$y=\frac{x^2}{x}$$
and
$$y=x$$

For the first function, if we don't divide both the numerator and the denominator by x, then the domain of it is the real line except the point x = 0, which is different from the domain of the second function.

Comment: These are not technically the same, as you have noted. One has a removable singularity at $0$, the other does not, but otherwise they take the same values everywhere.

Comment: These functions have different domains, so they are technically different functions.  It is common, however, to disregard this when it is convenient to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are not the same function, since they have different domains.
For two function to be the same they should have the same domain and the same mapping rules.